# Using husky to parse git commit message

Tags: git, githooks, husky, git-husky

How do I use husky to check for a particular git commit message pattern? Whenever the `git commit  -m "message"` command is invoked, I want to parse the message. How could I do this? How could I receive the git commit message and initiate the parsing?

Currently, my package.json has husky included:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "commit-msg": "./shell-scripts/commit-msg-hook.sh && commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
},
```

But I am not sure what to do in shell script file. How do I receive the commit message and then parse it?

Here is the shell script, that I am trying. It is very similar to what the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) has

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

echo message

$regex = /([#) #([0-9])* ([A-Z])\w+/

if !$regex.match(message)
puts "Incorrect format"
exit 1
end
```

Comment: Why a downvote? Please let me know, If I missed anything

Comment: What do you mean "parse the message"? In terms of receiving the commit message, look at what commitlint is doing and see https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky#access-git-params-and-stdin.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to parse the message and check for the existence of `#` in the commit message

Comment: And what specific problem have you had with that? What's in your script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have added the script that I tried with

Comment: @jonrsharpe But the script fails to run with an error message `./shell-scripts/commit-msg-hook.sh:4:in read': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe File name that has the commit message? I am not sure.

Comment: But you don't actually pass any arguments when you call the script. `ARGV` gives access to the command line arguments, but only if there are any. Again, compare with how commitlint is being used.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I took this from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy. From what I read, the first argument is the filename that has the commit message. Would you know a way? I just want to make sure that the commit message has `#taskid` in there. I have integrated `husky` with `commitlint` but still I will need to ensure the pattern parsing myself. [at least this is what I have understood reading the commitlint rules]

Comment: It *would* be, if git was calling it directly, but Husky's taken over so you need to follow their docs. You're calling two things in your script, why don't you try *doing the same thing for both*?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks

> The only argument passed to this hook is the name of the file that contains > the message.

I am not a ruby expert but working on a shell script I ran into a similar problem where my `$1` was not giving me the message as I would hope so but rather a path to a file. so doing
`commit_message="$(cat "$1")"` gets me the actual message to then validate.